# JSON.stringify() so that object fields are on one line

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I need to export data I get from the server as a .txt-file

The structure I get looks like that:

```
{
  "value": {
    "name": "A",
    "mandatory": true,
    "contentMandatory": true,
    "multipleAllowed": false,
    "fixed": true
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "value": {
        "name": "Aa",
        "mandatory": false,
        "contentMandatory": true,
        "multipleAllowed": false,
        "mergeStrategy": {
          "_type": "PrioritizedSourceStrategy"
        },
        "fixed": false
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "value": {
            "name": "Aaa",
            "mandatory": false,
            "contentMandatory": false,
            "multipleAllowed": true,
            "fixed": false
          },
          "children": [
            {
              "value": {
                "name": "AaaA",
                "mandatory": true,
                "contentMandatory": true,
                "multipleAllowed": false,
                "fixed": false
              },
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "value": {
            "name": "AaB",
            "mandatory": false,
            "contentMandatory": false,
            "multipleAllowed": true,
            "fixed": false
          },
          "children": [
            {
              "value": {
                "name": "AaBa",
                "mandatory": true,
                "contentMandatory": true,
                "multipleAllowed": false,
                "fixed": false
              },
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

But I need the structure to look like this in the file:

```
"name": "A", "mandatory": true, "contentMandatory": true, "multipleAllowed": false,
  "name": "Aa", "mandatory": false, "contentMandatory": true,  "multipleAllowed": false, "mergeStrategy": { "_type": "PrioritizedSourceStrategy"}
    "name": "Aaa", "mandatory": false, "contentMandatory": false, "multipleAllowed": true,
      "name": "AaaA", "mandatory": true, "contentMandatory": true, "multipleAllowed": false,
    "name": "AaB", "mandatory": false, "contentMandatory": false, "multipleAllowed": true,
       "name": "AaBa", "mandatory": true, "contentMandatory": true, "multipleAllowed": false,
...
```

So I need to remove some object fields (like "fixed") and display the fields that are left in one line per object.
Whats the best way to archive this result?

Comment: Don't know how do you think to create the txt file, but you may need something like this: `JSON.stringify(YOUR_DATA).replaceAll('"name": ', '\n"name": ')` . This adds a breakline '\n' before every substring 'name: '.

Answer (score 0):

The structure you want is erronous as you have duplicate properties. If this is the structure you want:

```
{
"name": "A",
"mandatory": true,
"contentMandatory": true,
"multipleAllowed": false,
"children": [
    {
    "name": "Aa",
    "mandatory": false,
    "contentMandatory": true,
    "multipleAllowed": false,
    "mergeStrategy": { "_type": "PrioritizedSourceStrategy" },
    "children": [
        {
        "name": "Aaa",
        "mandatory": false,
        "contentMandatory": false,
        "multipleAllowed": true,
        "children": [
            {
            "name": "AaaA",
            "mandatory": true,
            "contentMandatory": true,
            "multipleAllowed": false
            }
        ]
        },
        {
        "name": "AaB",
        "mandatory": false,
        "contentMandatory": false,
        "multipleAllowed": true,
        "children": [
            {
            "name": "AaBa",
            "mandatory": true,
            "contentMandatory": true,
            "multipleAllowed": false
            }
        ]
        }
    ]
    }
]
}
```

Then use this code snippet:

```
var parsedObject = parse(obj)

function parse(obj) {
   let children = obj.children.map(child => parse(child))
   return { name, mandatory, contentMandatory, multipleAllowed, mergeStrategy, children } = {...obj.value, children}
}
```

I'm using map and object destructuring to keep the properties I want.